# How to show label in jqplot on mouse over

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqplot

I am using JQplot for first time ,

I am using the following array to plot bar graph :

```
var bar1 = [[1,30,'s'],[2,40,'o'],[3,50,'l'],[4,60,'a'],[5,70,'n']];


var bar2 = [[1,30,'s'],[2,40,'o'],[3,50,'l'],[4,60,'a'],[5,70,'n']];



var bar3 = [[1,30,'s'],[2,40,'o'],[3,50,'l'],[4,60,'a'],[5,70,'n']];
```

I am getting the graph as it is expected but I want to show label which I have assigned to them.

But I dont know how to show that .
I am able to show the some information using following function (bind):

```
$('#chart1').bind('jqplotDataHighlight', 
            function (ev, seriesIndex, pointIndex, data,pointLabels) {
                $('#chart2').html('series: '+seriesIndex+', point: '+pointIndex+', data: '+data+');
            }
```

I wanted to show labels also which I have assigned to each bar.
How to do this ?

Thank You

Comment: refer: http://www.jqplot.com/tests/rotated-tick-labels.php

Comment: I am able to show label on graph by using the pointLable {show true}, but I wanted to show label in another div of my html on mouse click on a particular bar